# How to make unclickable icon inside clickable div?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a div rows which are clickable. Each row has icon inside it.

```
<div className="row" ....>
<icon className="filter".../>
</div>
```

I tried using  `pointer-events: none;` on the icon.  but it didn't work

How can I make those icons unclickable while the whole div is clickable?

Comment: Can you describe what you mean by "make unclickable"? Explain in greater detail what you expect behavior to be compared to current observed behavior?

Comment: You can achieve this effect _(ie. clickable parent, unclickable children)_ using `event.target` and [Event Delegation](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate).

Answer (score 1):

Your icon is placed inside `div`, so `icon` is clickable.

So try to place them side by side to have `icon` unclickable:

```css
div {
    display: flex;
}

div > div {
   background: orange;
   cursor: pointer;
}

div > icon {
   cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div className="row">
      1234567
    </div>
    <icon className="filter">2</icon>
</div>
```

Comment: But It needs to be for each row

Comment: @Dave you are right. Your icon placed inside div. This is a reason why icon has clickable cursor as you are hovering over `div`. So you can edit your HTML to get desired result.